# loading an image into asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, iis, directory

I've come across an obstacle I can't handle with altough I've been through many topics related to. I'm beginner in ASP.NET and I'd like to load an image into `.aspx` page, yet somehow it never renders. I'm using VS 2015, in the properties of the projects, on the tab Web, there's `IIS Express` chosen. I know that browser cannot read from the local disk, yet I can't manage to do it using virtual directory neither. What's more I am also unable to create a new one (I'm running VS under administrator account).

Based on other posts in this subject, in `applicationhost.config` I tried to modify physical path related to virtual path as:

```
         <sites>
            <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Temp\images" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>
```

In code behind I've tried many things, like:

```
try
            {
                //bitmap i Graphics
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200);
                {...}
                string url = @"C:\Temp\images\test.gif";
                string url1 = "~/test.gif";
                bmp.Save(url,ImageFormat.Png);
                bmp.Dispose();
                g.Dispose();
                imgTheImage.Visible = true;
                imgTheImage.ImageUrl = url1;
                lblErros.Text = "";
            }
```

Yet, it doesn't work. I mean the image is not being rendered. Could anyone help me make it happen? How can I point to the virtual directory corresponding to the physical path so that I could load a file? The file exists for sure, cause I'm creating it using GDI+ in runtime and it shows in `C:\Temp\images`. I'm not really familiar with this IIS yet, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and sorry if I forgot to write about any important matter!:)

**EDIT:**
This works, when I change the `url` variable to `@"C:\Users\pablo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GDI_Asp\GDI_Asp\test.gif"` which is ofc my project folder. So it seems like I didn't change the physical path to my virtual directory, but I don't know how I can do it, if the changes made by hand don't work.

Comment: Is this so you can dynamically generate images to render in your page, instead of them being static assets?

Comment: why don't you use the project's root directory?

Comment: @Kev Not really, that is not the matter. I mean, in this case, yes, I'm generating it dynamically, but my point is what should I do if I need to load it from some other directory from a local disk than the app folder.

Comment: @SankarRaj Because I would like to be able to choose from where I can load it, just to learn:)

Comment: Give read access on temp folder in question to app pool's identity.